# Django runserver error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Deleted folder'

Tags: python, django

I hope you are doing well.

I just started studying Django with the Meta back-end Cert.

I created my first project inside a venv and ran the server just as instructed.

Then I deleted the first folders, and tried to practice starting from zero.

When I create the new project folder I do the following steps:

1. create the venv -> py -m venv env
2. activate the venv -> env\scripts\activate
3. install django -> pip3 install django
4. create the project -> django-admin startproject new_sample
5. change directory -> cd new_sample
6. try to runserver -> py manage.py runserver
7. Error

Below the console response, it tries to reach a deleted folder.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named **'C:\django_projects\project1'** **THE DELETED FOLDERS**

```
(env) PS C:\new_django_folder\project4\new_sample> py manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 81, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1318, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\django_projects\\project1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\new_sample\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\new_sample\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 425, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 84, in close_all
    for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 76, in all
    return [
           ^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\new_django_folder\project4\env\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1318, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named **'C:\\django_projects\\project1'** **THE DELETED FOLDERS**
```

Please let me know how to fix that, so I can continue learning.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall python and vscode multiple times.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Did you modify any files in the project, move/copy the project from another location, or redefine any environment variables? It's strange that it would look for anything in `C:\django_projects\project1` because the `manage.py` script is in `C:\new_django_folder\project4\new_sample`.

Comment: Hello Mr. Michael Ruth, thank you for your help. It was just that, I manualy defined a environment variable for Django when trying to fix another thing and forgot about that. And again thank you, have a nice day.